# RStudio - How can I have a 3 columns layout?

Tags: r, ide, rstudio

I'm desperately trying to have as default a 3 columns layout in RStudio and can't manage to obtain it.

I tried to find some documentation, but found nothing with some details or explanation on the "panes" parameters of the rstudio-prefs.json file.

In "C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\RStudio\rstudio-prefs.json", I saw that it is possible to add a source column using "additional_source_columns": 1 but it is automatically set back to 0 every time I restart R and the problem is that it creates an untitled script in addition to the one I'm opening.

Here are the steps I have to perform to obtain the final layout I'm looking for.

Open a script by double clicking on it

[image]

Press CTRL + F7 to add a source column

[image]

Drag and drop my script to the left column

[image]

remove the 'untitled' script

[image]

Thank you for your help ! A link to any documentation that you may know of that I didn't find would be life-saving.

Best

Comment: Hi @Ignatu5. I just wanted to let you know that with the new version of RStudio that was released yesterday, there is a more convenient way of doing what you want. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, you can't have a 3 column setup as the default. It's an [open Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2854), marked as an enhancement and added to the "Later" milestone with no due date.

However, with version `2022.02.0+443` (February 2022) of RStudio you can do the following:

- Uncheck the option "Restore last opened documents on startup" in Global Options. This will have RStudio open project with no source panes at all.
- Using the new option "Open file in Source Column" to open your first file in a new column. This will give you the three columns layout you're looking for.

I would add the "Open file in new column" as a keyboard shortcut, for example `CTRL + O`. Your workflow would then be:

1. Open RStudio
2. `CTRL + O` to open your first script
3. Open more scripts any way you want - they will be added to the first column.

Comment: Thank you for the solution you proposed. This new option works indeed like a charm !

Comment: Ahhh so close.. now if only you could make the source column in the middle instead of the only option being to the left.